# I am developing react native app, in that i need to support upload files using OneDrive,Dropbox . Is there any way to get it done

Tags: react-native, dropbox, onedrive

I need to pick files from onedrive and dropbox. Is there any npm modules available.

Comment: I think you may try react-native-file-uploader, react-native-file-picker, react-file-picker. I have not used all of them. But i think this would solve your problem.LET ME KNOW IF IT WORKS OR NOT

Comment: Hello. any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I ran into the same issue. Spent a while finding the best solution.

Using an in-browser package [react-native-inappbrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) and the deepLink functionality. I was able to solve the issue.
You will have to look at the OneDrive/Dropbox documentation for allowing a RedirectUI for a `react-native` app.

```js
const redirectUrl = 'com.******.*******://auth'

export const tryDeepLinking = async () => {
  const loginUrl =
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
  const redirectUrl = getDeepLink();
  const url = `${loginUrl}?redirect_url=
    ${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl,)}
    &client_id=${encodeURIComponent('**********',)}
    &response_type=${encodeURIComponent('token')}
    &scope=${encodeURIComponent(
    'openid Files.ReadWrite.All offline_access',
    )}`;
  try {
    if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
      const result: any = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectUrl, {
        // iOS Properties
        ephemeralWebSession: false,
        // Android Properties
        showTitle: false,
        enableUrlBarHiding: true,
        enableDefaultShare: false,
      });
      const paramsString = result.url.split('#')[1];
      let params: any = {};
      paramsString.split('&').forEach(kv => {
        const keyValue = kv.split('=', 2);
        params[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
      });
      await setStorageAzureToken(params.access_token);
      Alert.alert('Response', 'Success');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('InAppBrowser is not supported :/');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    Alert.alert('Something’s wrong with the app :(');
  }
};
```

This is what I am using to get the OneDrive access token, from there you are able to use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/` api's to manage files.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker).

Comment: this is not what he wants. this library only support upload file from local storage.